# Joomla! SQL Query does not insert data in the database

Tags: sql, joomla, joomla2.5

I use Joomla 2.5 and I'm trying to insert data into my database

This is my code

```
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = 
    "INSERT INTO '#__restaurantes' ('nombre', 'direccion', 'localizacion', 'cod_postal', 'telefono', 'web')
    VALUES ( JRequest::getCmd('restaurante'), JRequest::getCmd('direccion'), JRequest::getCmd('localizacion'), JRequest::getCmd('postal'), JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa'), JRequest::getCmd('web') )";
    $db->setQuery( $query );
    $db->query();
```

Everything is fine and I don´t have any errors, but it doesn't insert anything.

Any idea? thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP (I'm assuming that's what you're using?), but some DB connectors require you to commit INSERT commands

Comment: yes, I am using PHP and documentation of joomla http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#insertid.28.29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put quotes around your values:

```
$restaurante = JRequest::getCmd('restaurante');
$direccion = JRequest::getCmd('direccion');
$localizacion = JRequest::getCmd('localizacion');
$postal = JRequest::getCmd('postal');
$telefonoEmpresa = JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa');
$telefonoEmpresa = JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa');
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__restaurantes' ('nombre', 'direccion', 'localizacion', 'cod_postal', 'telefono', 'web') VALUES ( '$restaurante', '$direccion', '$localizacion', '$postal', '$telefonoEmpresa', '$web' )";
$db->setQuery( $query );
```

Also, you should add this code after your query to catch any errors:

```
if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    JError::raiseError("Error", $db->stderr());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When trying to figure what's going wrong with your Joomla! code the first thing to do is set the Error Reporting level in the `Site->Global Configuration->Server` screen to `Maximum` (or `Development` if you don't have any extensions installed that crash Joomla! under `Maximum`.

This will not only report more errors and their details it will also provide a "Debug Console" which has a section called "Database Queries" that will show exactly what is happening with all of the SQL queries.

Now, on the code you've provided:

1. The `$query` won't work the way you've structured it as each `JRequest()` will just be treated as a syntax error.
2. There are two ways to extract the values, either store them in temporary variables before hand and then use those in the `$query` or fix your initial method by using concatenation to build the query.

#### Method 1

In PHP when you [wrap a string in " double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) the string is processed by PHP and any variables or escape sequences are replaced.

```
$restaurante = JRequest::getCmd('restaurante');
$direccion = JRequest::getCmd('direccion');
$localizacion = JRequest::getCmd('localizacion');
$postal = JRequest::getCmd('postal');
$telefonoEmpresa = JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa');
$telefonoEmpresa = JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa');
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__restaurantes' ('nombre', 'direccion', 'localizacion', 'cod_postal', 'telefono', 'web') VALUES ( $restaurante, $direccion, $localizacion, $postal, $telefonoEmpresa, $web )";
$db->setQuery( $query );
```

#### Method 2

To use the `JRequest()` calls as you have you will need to use the '.' ([concatenation operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)) to build the string and make the calls in line.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO '#__restaurantes' ('nombre', 'direccion', 'localizacion', 'cod_postal', 'telefono', 'web') VALUES ("
       . JRequest::getCmd('restaurante') . ", "
       . JRequest::getCmd('direccion') . ", "
       . JRequest::getCmd('localizacion') . ", "
       . JRequest::getCmd('postal') . ", "
       . JRequest::getCmd('telefonoEmpresa') . ", "
       . JRequest::getCmd('web'). " )";
```

#### Things you should be aware of:

1. `JRequest` shouldn't be used unless you're trying to support Joomla! 1.5 as well as 2.5. You should use [`JInput()`](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) - read that link for more information.
2. The query you're building is an old style string query and doesn't take advantage of JDatabases abstraction layer, [you should read more about it here](http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/9-developer/135-database-upgrades-in-joomla-16.html).
3. `JRequest::getCmd()` filters all values and only allows characters in the set [A-Za-z0-9.-_], so any non-ascii values will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

This also should work:

```
$data =new stdClass();
$data->id = null;
$data->field1 = 'val1';
$data->field2 = 'val2';
$data->field3 = 'val3';

$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->insertObject( '#__mytable', $data, id );
```

stdClass is a php base class from which all other classes are extended.

'id' is the name for your primary key.